# Increase all elements of a List in C++

Tags: c++, list, element

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>


using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::list;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void showContents(T& input)
{
 typename T::iterator it;
 for (it=input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++)
{ cout << *it << " "; }
 cout << endl;
}



int main()
{
int B[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
cout<< "The first array is: "<< "\n";
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {cout<< B[i]<< " ";}



vector<int> KVec(B,B+10);
cout << "\n \n" << "The first vector is: " << endl;
showContents(KVec);



list<int> BList(B,B+10);
cout << "\n" << "The first list is: " << endl;
showContents(BList);




int BCopy [10];
cout<< "\n" <<"The second array is: "<< endl;
for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    BCopy[i] = B[i];
    BCopy[i] += 2;
    cout<< BCopy[i]<< " ";
}

vector<int> KVec2(KVec);
cout<< "\n \n" << "The second vector is: "<< endl;

for (int i = 0; i<KVec2.size(); i++){
    KVec2[i] += 3;
}
showContents(KVec2);


cout<< "\n" << "The second list is: "<< endl;

std::list<int> BList2 (BList);
for (std::list<int>::iterator b = BList.begin(); b!=BList.end(); ++b)
{
    ( *b += 5 );
    showContents(BList2);

}
```

This is the code I have. I was able to correctly copy all the arrays, vectors , and lists and increasing the values of those accordingly. The only one I have not been able to increment in the list. My goal is to increment all the elements of the second list by 5. I have been using mulitple references to try and do it but I have tried everything and can not get it to work. Below I have my latest attempt at trying to increment all the values but that doesn't seem to work either so now I need help. That is the only thing left to do in this assignment so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is in C++, not C - please use the appropriate tag to get the C++ community's help (edit the question).

Comment: Off topic: `using namespace std;` renders all of the above `using` statements useless.

Comment: You are incrementing values in `Blist` but printing values of `Blist2`.

Comment: @Zereges thank you. I fixed the problem, I knew it was something small I was tweaking just couldn't figure it out. Appreciate you

Comment: Only the relevant portions would help...
Why is showContents() inside your for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment fixed your problem, I am converting it into an answer.

You copy constructed `BList2` using values from `BList` (I am changing to brace initialization to avoid [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)). But then, you are iterating over values of `BList` again. Also, you don't need parentheses around `*b += 5`. Finally, your `showContents` function is probably meant to be outside of the loop.

```
std::list<int> BList2 {BList};
for (std::list<int>::iterator b = BList2.begin(); b != BList2.end(); ++b)
{
    *b += 5;
}
showContents(BList2);
```